# No matching distribution found for mediapipe

Tags: python, pycharm, mediapipe

Trying to install the mediapipe package and keep getting these errors.

[image: Error Message]

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

I am using the latest version of Python (3.12.0), and latest version of community PyCharm (2023.2.2).

1. Attempted to download package from PyCharm to no avail
2. Attempted `pip3 install mediapipe` | Which gives this error
3. Attempted PyCharm recommended remedy, path of the commands seems to be incorrect syntax, and I simply don't know enough yet to see the issue. ex.

```
C:\Users\ahami>C:\Users\ahami\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\ahami>C:\Users\ahami\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install mediapipe
C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: From their [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files:~:text=Programming%20Language) it appears that mediapipe is not available to python 3.12 yet.. you should consider downgrading to 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.12 is not supported by Mediapipe yet. use Python 3.7 to 3.10.

Comment: why not 3.11? There are whl files for that version also on pypi

Comment: if it's work, than try3.11? 3.10 it's ok =)